# NetBeans 8.2 does not open on Mac OS

Tags: netbeans

I am trying to start NetBeans 8.2 on a Macbook Pro and it's not working.

It shows the splash screen, then after a while it shuts down without starting anything.

Running from the command-line I can see this error:

```
Oct 02, 2017 7:40:28 PM org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory register
SEVERE: No way to find original stream handler for jar protocol
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field transient java.net.URLStreamHandler java.net.URL.handler accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @7823a2f9
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:337)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:281)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:169)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:82)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader.<clinit>(JarClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl.execute(MainImpl.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl.main(MainImpl.java:85)
    at org.netbeans.Main.main(Main.java:83)
```

Looks like Java 9 got bundled with it and it's causing an error. The documentation implies that NetBeans 8.2 uses JDK 8!?

How to use my own java to run NetBeans, or how to get NetBeans to start without this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, NetBeans 8.2 does use JDK 1.8, and specifically does not support JDK 1.9.

It's unclear from the OP which version of Java is desired to run with NetBeans, but the version of NetBeans to use is governed by the version of Java to be used:

[1] For Java 8, use  Netbeans 8.2. Note that **Java 9 is not supported**. You can download NetBeans 8.2 bundled with JDK 8u141 for Mac OS here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html

Once it has been installed it no specific configuration for Java should be necessary.

[2] For Java 9 you must use a Development Build of NetBeans. That can be downloaded from http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/ but be sure that **Mac OS X** is selected from the **Platform** drop list before clicking **Download**.

For any version of NetBeans you can specify your own version of Java as follows:

- Start NetBeans and select **Java Platforms** from the **Tools** menu.
- Click the **Add Platform...** button.
- Complete the wizard to locate the version of Java you want to use.

One final point: there is no problem having multiple versions of NetBeans installed and running concurrently using different JDKs, typically NetBeans 8.2 with JDK 1.8 and NetBeans Dev Build with JDK 1.9.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Update:

If NetBeans closes itself down on startup it may have an invalid JDK path. To change the JDK that NetBeans uses:

- Locate the file **netbeans.conf**. It should be in the **etc** directory under the NetBeans installation directory.
- Edit that file in a text editor. Locate the line containing the property **netbeans_jdkhome**. On my Windows 10 installation it looks like this:

  **netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"**
- Change the value for that property to specify the path to the desired JDK, save the file and restart NetBeans.

Comment: I don't even have JDK 9. As I said, it seems the Mac release ships with JDK 9 and that didn't work.

Comment: @Renato I was not aware that Mac ships with JDK9, but I agree that the stack trace looks like NetBeans 8.2 is trying to use JDK 9. I have updated my post to explain how to tell NetBeans which JDK to use on startup.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. This line in the conf file was commented out. When I set it to my latest JDK8 it worked. I don't know how it was trying to use Java9... I do have EA versions installed with sdkman but they shouldn't be visible to NetBeans (or??) as I don't use them.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed in the comments:

I had tried to set `netbeans_jdkhome in /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf` to point to **JDK 10,** but still it did not work.

I had to install JDK 8, and set netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home"

**Uninstalling JDK 10** and **using JDK 8** worked for me and setting `netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home"` worked quite well.

Comment: This worked for me. It's important to know that jdk1.8.0_181 is the version of Java 8 that you have installed (I'm installed jdk1.8.0_211).

Comment: Setting `netbeans_jdkhome` to point to **JDK 10** did not work for you because NetBeans 8.2 does not support any JDK version > 8.

Answer (score 2):

macOS 10.13.5
JavaJDK 10 installed as "System" JVM

I was able to install NetBeans, but unable to get it to function.  Window would open, clicking on "New Project" or "New File" did absolutely nothing.

Was able to get it working (all modules and servers) by going into the configuration file at
    /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf

and editing the commented out path to JDK at the bottom of the file!

Cheers!

Comment: Used @skomisa's windows suggestion, and it worked for mac!

Comment: This worked for me on MacOS 10.13.6. I had originally downloaded Netbeans 8.2, and JDK 10.0.2. Netbeans started, but could not open New File, New Project.
I had tried to set netbeans_jdkhome  in /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf to point to JDK 10, but still it did not work. I had to install JDK 8, and set 
netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home"
 which worked

Comment: @Yusuf Did you remove the `#` before the ` netbeans_jdkhome` line?

Comment: @jay No need to remove `#`

Answer (score 1):

Check Java JDK is installed on Mac, NetBeans 8.2 does use JDK 1.8(Java SE 8)

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V

Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    12.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 12.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_211, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home
```

---

if not , just install (no need remove exist JDK)
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

---

modify `/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf`

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Answer (score 0):

For NetBeans 8.2 JDK 1.8 should be used. If you installed JDK 1.9 or JDK 10.0 to your MacBook, you must uninstall that from your computer.

Comment: correct, but no need to uninstall the others. Just fix the path pointing to JDK in Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf  and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I'm using Apache Netbeans 12.0 so I had to change my OpenJDK version from 19.0 to 14.0 and update the path in order to finally work.

No need to uninstall the 19.0, just install the version that works with the Apache that you have and update the path:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk14.0.jdk/Contents/Home"
```