# Netbeans on MacOS X Big Sur no JDK Found

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I am trying to install Netbeans 8.2 under Big Sur. All my attempts failed, each time I get "No JDK found". I have already JDK 1.8.
Thanks for any idea!

Comment: Have you set JAVA_HOME path pointing to JDK? and Path variable pointing bin of JDK?

Comment: Yes.Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home for JAVA_HOME and .../bin for PATH. Strange is that /usr/libexec/java_home points to location of JRE not JDK. before Big Sur I remember /usr/libexec/java_home it was just a sumbolik link to JAVA_HOME path. Now, after Big Sir it is a binary file.

Comment: Any idea? When I made upgrade from Catalina to BigSur Netbeans stoped working. It was not able to find the proper path but I could change it in the config file. Then I reinstalled BigSur from scratch and cannot Netbeans cannot start installing.

Comment: @xeon [1] Just a wild guess, but is it possible that your upgrade to Big Sur bundled a JDK > 1.8? However, since you set the path in the NetBeans config that doesn't seem relevant. [2] Probably not helpful, but also see [NetBeans 8.2 does not open on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46530960/2985643). [3] Could you update your question with a screen shot showing exactly where you get the _"No JDK found"_ error?

Comment: tried also with Java 11 and then with Apache Netbeans and same result. Tried also to install Eclipse on both ways: through installer and through homebrew and the same. No error with Eclipse but it doesn't start. I face the same issue like this threat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63570470/no-jdk-found-when-trying-to-install-apache-netbeans-ide-on-macos-big-sure.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS Big Sur - Apache Netbeans 12 Missing Java Home Solution

Open Terminal

vi as sudo to the netbeans.conf file

`sudo vi /Applications/NetBeans/Apache\ NetBeans\ 12.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf`

Locate the netbeans_jdkhome parameter

Uncomment the Line and make sure its equal to the $JAVA_HOME path e.g

`netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Quit Netbeans and restart it, it works like Magic
Happy Coding [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oWY9.png)

Comment: The problem is that Netbeans cannot be installed. When try to install I retrieve the error mentioned in the post. Still some workaround found. To go on my time machine previous backups with Catalina versions and copy from there the whole Netbeans folder.

Comment: For me `brew install netbeans` downloaded and installed netbeans 12.x

Answer (score 0):

As I can read around it is possible to run without any issues only with latest java version. You can make Netbeans work by installing Java 15 for example, checking $JAVA_HOME and I hope there are would be a fix shortly as I am also fun of java 8.